# How should I differentiate vector of $~\operatorname{rot}~$?

Tags: derivatives, vectors, rotations, divergence-theorem

The following stuff handles a system where no electric charge exists(i.e. free space).

$$\operatorname{rot}\boldsymbol{H}_{}=\sigma\boldsymbol{E}_{}+\epsilon{\partial\boldsymbol{E}_{}\over\partial\mathrm{t}}\tag{1}$$

$$\operatorname{rot}\boldsymbol{E}_{}=-\mu{\partial\boldsymbol{H}_{}\over\partial\mathrm{t}}\tag{2}$$

$$\color{fuchsia}{-\operatorname{rot}\operatorname{rot}\boldsymbol{E}_{}=\sigma\mu{\partial\boldsymbol{E}_{}\over\partial\mathrm{t}}+\epsilon\mu{\partial^2\boldsymbol{E}_{}\over\partial\mathrm{t}^2}}\tag{3}$$

The book says that eqn 3 can be obained differentiating eqn1 by$~t~$and substituting eqn2 to that eqn to eliminate$~\boldsymbol{H}_{}~$

So I started from the following.

$${\partial\over\partial\mathrm{t}}\left(\operatorname{rot}\boldsymbol{H}_{}\right)={\partial\over\partial\mathrm{t}}\left(\sigma\boldsymbol{E}_{}+\epsilon{\partial\boldsymbol{E}_{}\over\partial\mathrm{t}}\right)\tag{4}$$

My brain has freezed to proceed operations from here.

$$\boldsymbol{H}_{}:=\text{magnetic field vector}\tag{5}$$

$~r,\theta~$may determine a value of this vector. And these 2 parameters may be determined by one independent variable$~t~$

Following given list may help to resolve what I want to do.

$$
\begin{cases}
\operatorname{rot}\boldsymbol{H}_{}=\boldsymbol{J}_{}+{\partial\boldsymbol{D}_{}\over\partial\mathrm{t}}\\
\operatorname{rot}\boldsymbol{E}_{}=-{\partial\boldsymbol{B}_{}\over\partial\mathrm{t}}\\
\operatorname{div}\boldsymbol{D}_{}=\sigma\\
\operatorname{div}\boldsymbol{B}_{}=0\\
\boldsymbol{D}_{}=\epsilon\boldsymbol{E}_{}\\
\boldsymbol{B}_{}=\mu\boldsymbol{H}_{}\\
\boldsymbol{J}_{}=\sigma\boldsymbol{E}_{}\\
\operatorname{div}\boldsymbol{E}_{}=0\\
\operatorname{div}\boldsymbol{H}_{}=0\\
\epsilon,\mu,\sigma\leftarrow~~\text{constants}
\end{cases}\tag{6}
$$

I need your advice.

In the first place , how can I differentiate with vector of $~\operatorname{rot}~$?

Which article(s) is/are suitable to be read to resolve my problem?

Comment: I can see your equations but you should expand on what is your difficulty. You might want to migrate to physics stack exchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a standard excersise. The key thing to notice is that the curl operator and the time partial derivative can commute because of Clairaut's Theorem, as explained in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1714711/695196). In your case, this is applied to get
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\nabla \times \vec{H} \right) =\nabla \times  \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\vec{H} \right) \tag{0}
$$
and thus
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\nabla \times \vec{H} \right) &= \frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\sigma \vec{E}  + \varepsilon\frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t} \right)\\
\overset{(0)}{\mathbin{\color{blue}{\implies}}}\nabla \times  \left(\color{purple}{\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\vec{H}} \right) &=\sigma \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}  + \varepsilon\frac{\partial^2 \vec{E}}{\partial t^2} \\
\overset{(2)}{\mathbin{\color{blue}{\implies}}}\nabla \times  \left(\color{purple}{-\frac{1}{\mu} \nabla \times \vec{E}} \right) &=\sigma \frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}  + \varepsilon\frac{\partial^2 \vec{E}}{\partial t^2} \\
\mathbin{\color{blue}{\implies}}-\nabla \times  \left( \nabla \times \vec{E} \right) &=\sigma \mu\frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}  + \varepsilon\mu\frac{\partial^2 \vec{E}}{\partial t^2} 
\end{align}
where you get the desired result, remembering that you can factor out $\varepsilon$ and $\mu$ from the derivatives since they're constants.